# How do I declare multiple arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, declaration

I'm a beginner.

How do I declare 100 different integer arrays?
Typing it all would be a bad idea.

My approach: I made structure arrays each containing an integer array inside them but the problem is that every structure array got to have a different size integer array so what do I do now?

Consider the size of integer arrays to be a function of the number of structure array they're in

Comment: Dynamic allocation?

Comment: How different *are* they? If it varies by just a few elements, you could allocate all of the same size and just leave some elements unused.

Comment: Declate a single array of 100 pointers, then malloc() each of them as needed.

Comment: Flexible array member may help. Consider showing your attempt, and a description of what failed.

Comment: You mention "your approach," but you haven't posted any code -- please do post your existing, even if incomplete, implementation when asking on SO.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is by dynamically allocating an array of `n` `int*`s and then allocating an array of `k` `int`s using each of the pointers just allocated to point to each seperate pool of new `int`s, I've added and commented an example below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    int** arr;
    /* create a pool of 100 int* */
    arr = malloc( 100 * sizeof(int*) );
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        /* assign each pointer to an array of length i */
        arr[i] = malloc( i * sizeof(int) );
        for( int j = 0; j < i; ++j )
        {
            /* assign each integer to j (just so they aren't all the same) */
            arr[i][j] = j;
        }
    }

    /* check we've done everything correctly by printing every int allocated */
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        for( int j = 0; j < i; ++j )
        {
            printf( "%d\n", arr[i][j] );
        }
    }

    /* free up the memory, this isn't required in such a small program, 
    but any memory dynamically allocated will leak if not free'd */
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; ++i )
    {
        free( arr[i] );
    }
    free( arr );
}
```

Comment: There's a lot of "magic numbers" in this code, plus `arr` can be defined and initialized on one line. Having a variable that represents the number of iterations in one spot would help with scaling this up later to handle *N* entries.